# Folding selected text

Tags: atom-editor

I like that in Atom text editor, you can hide code blocks to get a better overview. This is called *Folding* and is described [here](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/folding/). There it says:

> Finally, you can fold arbitrary sections of your code or text by making a selection and then typing <kbd>Alt+Ctrl+F</kbd> or choosing "Fold Selection" in the Command Palette.

I would like to make use of this, but it doesn't work for me. (I select a section of my code, then press the combination <kbd>Alt+Ctrl+F</kbd>, but nothing happens.) My operating system is Linux Mint 20.2 and the Atom version is 1.58.0.
I am looking for a fix or for a different method to fold selected text.

My use-case right now would be to fold [Python docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring). So if someone knows how to accomplish only that in Atom, you would also help me.

Answer (score 0):

Although I did not find out why the hotkey doesn't work, I found a solution that fits my needs. The Atom package [`custom-folds`](https://atom.io/packages/custom-folds) adds the functionality to define regions that may be folded.

After installing `custom-folds`, I added the lines `#<editor-folds` and `#</editor-fold>` at the beginning and end of the docstring, respectively:

```py
def average(a, b):
    #<editor-fold
    """
    Return the mean value of inputs a and b
    """
    #</editor-fold>
    return (a+b)/2
```

The commands `#<editor-fold` and `#</editor-fold>` are recognized and highlighted; also, a dropdown arrow appears where the code region can be folded or unfolded.